# issue in joining two tables using UNION

Tags: sql, union, teradata

I need to find target minus source table.Following is the details of tables:

Columns of Target table - customer_match :

```
 - ID
 - CUST_ID
 - USER_ID - has default value 'A'
```

Columns of Source table - sales1 :

```
 - id
```

Column of Source table - sales2

```
 - cu_id
```

Mapping looks like this:

```
 1. customer_match.ID = sales1.id
 2. customer_match.CUST_ID = sales2.cu_id
 3. customer_match.USER_ID = 'A'
```

Source tables should have a union join.

I have written query in teradata based on above requirement as:

```
sel 
ID
, CUST_ID
, USER_ID
from customer_match
MINUS

sel
id
,'A'
from sales1
UNION
sel
cu_id
,'A' 
from sales2
```

But this query does not satisfy my requirement as my both id and cu_id are getting mapped to only one column.
Can you please help me to correct my query as per the requirement.

Comment: You will need to relate `sales1.id` and `sales2.cu_id` to `JOIN` them. `UNION` is not the command you need.

Comment: Do you really need a relational `UNION JOIN`? This would be a `SELECT sales1.id, sales2.cust_id, 'A' as user_id FROM sales1 FULL JOIN sales2 ON 1=0`. But what are you really trying to do, can you show some actual data plus expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can't `union` two values in query. Use field name instead of it.

```
select
id
from sales1
UNION
select
cu_id
from sales2
```